# vb.net what is %Delay% and others

Tags: vb.net

So I was looking at some code from github and I came across many instances of code like this :

```
Dim num As Integer = C_Settings.Delay
Do Until num = 0
   Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
   num -= 1
Loop
```

What does this loop do? Is it something similar to just a normal sleep function or does this serve some other purpose? (keep in mind this is the first thing that runs when the program is started)

The C_Settings has this inside :

```
Public Shared Delay As Integer = "%Delay%"
```

Another example :

```
Public Shared SPL = C_Settings.SPL
```

C_Settings :

```
Public Shared SPL As String = "%SPL%"
```

I'm pretty new to coding in VB and I have no idea what this does or what this even is. Main question would be : why is it in "%%" and what does it do? I'd be grateful if anyone can explain.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. Apparently the .vb file is pre-processed with a tool that substitutes numbers. Which is an awful way of doing it, looking at the `As Integer = "%Delay%"`. They should have looked at T4 templates.

Comment: As to the question about what the loop does, it pauses for at least %Delay% seconds.  `Thread.Sleep` will block the current thread for at least the number of milliseconds given in the argument, allowing other threads to proceed.  It looks like in this context, it's waiting for some other startup tasks to complete.  It looks like a kind of gross hack where it really should be set up to wait on the actual thing that needs to be completed instead of using a guesstimate for how long it will take.